# Understanding K&R Ex 1-18

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm working on example 1-18 which is for a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines.

First question- When pasting in input, why does the program display the first line then wait for me to press enter to continue?

Second question- I'm expecting an input of

```
test\n
\n
\n
test\n
```

to output (new lines not actually printed)

```
test\n
test\n
```

Instead I'm getting the following

```
test


testtest

test
```

Where the first 2 tests are the pasted input, and the second 2 are the output. Where am I making a mistake? Also The fourth test doesn't display until enter is pressed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000    //maximum input line size

int get_line(char line[], int maxline);
void replacewhite(char line[], int length);

main() {

    int len;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while ((len = get_line(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {   // create lines < 1000 characters
        replacewhite(line, len);                    // replace excess whitespace at end of line
      // if len = 1, the line only has '\n', do nothing and get next line
        if(len > 1) {
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }   
    }   
    return 0;
}

int get_line(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) !=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;

    if (c=='\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }   
    s[i] = '\0';                                                 
return i;
}

// set index to end of line, move backwards to first printed character,
// add null terminator one position afterwards (new lines handled in printf)
void replacewhite(char s[], int length){
    int i;

    i = length;
    while(s[i] <= ' '){
        --i;
    }   
    s[i+1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Note: do not use identifiers starting with `_` (underscore).

Comment: Think about this: What happens if the line only contains whitespace (ever heared about _undefined behaviour_)? Are you aware that `'\n' <= ' '`? Why do you append newline anyway? A consistent behaviour of a function is always better/less confusing (either always newline, or never). Hint: use `size_t` for indexing into an array. That is the type used by `sizeof` and `strlen`. Also enable most compiler warnings.

Comment: All functions have some kind of return type including a void return type.  The main function is special.  It always has a 'int' return type.  The posted code is missing the return type modifier on the main() function.

Comment: in C, an array is address as offset 0 through length-1.   in the get_line() function, if the input is MAXLINE characters long,  then the statement: 's[i] = '\0';' is overrunning the end of the buffer, which is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  in the get_line() function, there is no need to append a '\n' to the end of the input buffer, (and see first part of this comment).

Comment: suggest deleting the get_line() function.  suggest, in main, replacing the 'while' statement with: 'while( fgets( line, MAX_LINE, stdin )'.  suggest replacing the call to removewhite() with 'if( line[0] !='\n' ) { replacewhite(line, strlen(line));  printf( .... ); }'.   Then can delete all reference to the 'len' variable

Comment: the statement: if( len > 1 ) can fail on windows, DOS, and similar systems where the newline is actually 2 characters

Comment: @Olaf The append new line was in the textbook.  I didn't catch the bad logic on the '\n' <= ' ' since it didnt fail spectacularly. Looked at it with GDB. I'm slightly more confused.  So after running, replacewhite sets a null byte at s[-11], so I've got to fix the logic on replacewhite.  When it returns, length is still 1 so it proceeds to get the next line.  So while the logic replacewhite logic is all screwy and needs to be fixed, shouldn't it still print the next line with printed characters immediately below the previous line? And why do I have to press enter to continue?

Comment: @user3629249 Tracking on the array indexing.  The for loop goes from 0..i<lim-1, in other words, i < 999, or 998.  The for loop leaves enough space to append \n at s[999] and \0 at s[1000]. Agree that \n isn't necessary, I'm just following along with the book right now. So far it's only introducted getchar() and putchar() for input. Also, running this on a linux box just to learn, acknowledge it wouldn't check newlines on windows properly.

Comment: I believe there's an assumption in the book that every line will have at a minimum a '\n', and not simply whitespace with no newline characters, otherwise the text's example wouldn't have included the line

for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) !=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)

I assumed there would have to be at least one '\n' on a given line.

Comment: @SamThode: I can hardly believe the function is written in the book as-is. If so, there should be an errata. Anyway, K&R is quite outdated now, as it not even covers C99, which actually introduced many modern features to C (some even might be incompatible with the older versions).

Comment: @Sam `\0 at s[1000]` is not good.  Only `s[0] ... s[999]` is usable.

Comment: haha yay for outdated text? http://www.iups.org/media/meeting_minutes/C.pdf see page 30 for the for loop I mentioned.

Comment: @chux: There is no overflow actually. However, for an empty line (or whitespace-only), `replacewhite` (better name would be rightstrip, btw.), that will go past index 0, making i negative! I assume that is the problem here.

Comment: @SamThode: It **is** outdated! the standard allows for **two** signatures for main for a _hosted environment_, Posix, Windows and MacOS al use this (MacOS actually somewhat extended), but all require to return `int` and pass argc/argv.

Comment: @Olaf  Agree about buffer over-run - just making clear concerning OP's comment about "\0 at s[1000]".  Yes `replacewhite()` is defective should the line not have any non-white-space.

Comment: @Olaf Yea I just flipped through the book to see if it would ever talk about argv/argc. It doesnt. Lot of stuff on pointers and memory though, which is one of the main reasons I'm working through it.  Now if I could fix my logic on this program so I could finally move on...

Comment: @chux: I see. Sorry, I did not completely read OPs text. He is shooting himself in the foot with this comment, as he seems not to understand why this cannot happen. (I fell into this trap for a moment, too, until I realized the ordering of loop-control conditions)

Comment: @SamThode: I gave you enough hints in my 2nd comment already. That is so simple, you really should find the solution yourself if you did not just copy/paste code. Oh, and apparently: it **did** fail spectacularily. And: newline **is** whitespace! (at least how you test for)

Comment: "Yea I just flipped through the book ..." Well, IIRC, it does. But that was not the point actually. Feel free to read the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). It's worth the time.